# Shortest way to answer probability / game question?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

> Your game piece is on the starting space, and the finish is 10 more spaces away. During each of your turns, you roll a fair six-sided die, and move that many spaces forward. However, if the result would put you past the finish, you do not move. What is the probability that you will reach the finish in 3 or fewer turns?

What is the shortest way to get this answer? I know the answer is 2/9, but curious what is the most efficient method of answering this?

**EDIT: The question (and the given answer / method to obtain in a long way can be found at this link: Check out this problem I found on Brilliant!
https://brilliant.org/practice/conditional-probability-casework-calculations/?problem=discrete-mathematics-problem-109432&chapter=conditional-probability-2**

**I would have simply copied and pasted the answer but couldn't get the graphics to display properly and it will be better displayed in the associated link.**

Comment: do you know the game Sorry? this reminds me of it

Comment: That is irrelevant to the conversation @Saketh... the question is about the mathematics of the scenario, not what it resembles in real life.  As for an approach, my initial instinct is to describe this with markov chains.  Alternatively, just list out the dice rolls that result in success.  Brute force listing them out is prone to error however as there are $6^3=216$ possible ways to throw three dice in succession

Comment: @EthanBolker the source of the problem gave an answer (I tried but was off by 1/9 , having looked at their answer I see why now). I can update question to provide the answer given.

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah I did brute force it and I thought it was also prone to error. I'll update the question to show the answer given in the long way.

Comment: As an aside, the link you give in the post would only work assuming the person has an account already active with brilliant.org.  It just takes normal users to a preview page and not to the problem in question.  If you have enough reputation to post images and are a windows user, try using the snipping tool (included in all modern versions of windows) to capture and crop an image of the problem and post that.

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry I thought that might have been a free question (I do have an account there). I'm on mobile but I'll do that at the computer tonight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To win in exactly 3 turns without "overshooting" can be done in $[x^{10}]((x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3)$ number of ways where $[x^n]$ represents taking the coefficient of the $x^n$ term in the expansion.  Here, that would correspond to $27$ different ways.  This occurs with probability $\frac{27}{6^3}$

To win in exactly 2 turns can be done in $[x^{10}](x+x^2+\dots+x^6)^2$ number of ways, here $3$ ways.  This occurs with probability $\frac{3}{6^2}$ and is mutually exclusive with the earlier case.

To win in exactly 3 turns while overshooting once can only occur as the sequence of rolls 5-6-5, 6-5-4, and 6-6-4, occurring with probability $\frac{3}{6^3}$.

This gives us a final total probability of $\frac{27+6\cdot 3+3}{6^3}=\frac{48}{216}=\frac{2}{9}$

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know, thank you. However, I'm grateful for everyone's responses, since I'm learning other ways to conceptualize / approach this problem, all of which are useful. But this is what I intuitively knew existed but couldn't nail down. Thanks!!

Comment: The "method" employed here is that of [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).  It may not be the most ideal for *calculating* things by hand, but still gives us an analytical way of writing down the answer even in hard problems and easy ways to calculate the numbers using technology.  For example, $[x^{1000}](x+x^2+\dots+x^6)^{500}$ would be the number of ways to roll a total of $1000$ using $500$ six-sided dice in sequence.  See also [generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Answer (score 4):

Win in 2 turns

Roll exactly 10 on 2 rolls.

Win in 3 turns.

Not roll exactly 2,3 or 10 on the first two rolls.

If you roll a 2 or a 3, you are still not in striking distance, if you roll a 10 you won in two rolls.

Roll exactly what you need to cross the goal with the 3rd roll.

Comment: This is a good way (better than I had conceived) to think about it. But at that point would you just brute force it to get the numbers?

Comment: Brute force is good as you build intuition around the combinatorics.